# How to find occurence of an event per minute within a time range using pyspark

Tags: python, scala, pyspark

```
| tweet id |  | tweet created minute |  | Game start minute |  | Game end minute |         
1001      145678                145600             145730   
1002      145678                145600             145730   
1005      145680                145600             145730   
12278     145687                145600             145730     
765558    145688                145600             145730     
724323    145689                145600             145730     
875857    145688                145600             145730     
79375     145685                145600             145730     
84666     145686                145600             145730     
335556    145687                145600             145730     
29990     145688                145600             145730     
56        145689                145600             145730 
968867    145690                145600             145730     
8452      145691                145600             145730   
1334      145679                145600             145730
```

There are 130 minutes in this match. How do I calculate the amount of tweets per minute? "tweet id" represents a unique tweet.

Expected result format:

| minutes | count of tweets |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming tweet id is unique and using Pyspark and raw rdd:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1001 ,145678, 145600, 145730),
(1002 ,145678, 145600, 145730),
(1005 ,145680, 145600, 145730), 
(12278 ,145687, 145600, 145730), 
(765558 ,145688, 145600, 145730), 
(724323 ,145689, 145600, 145730), 
(875857 ,145688, 145600, 145730), 
(79375 ,145685, 145600, 145730), 
(84666 ,145686, 145600, 145730), 
(335556 ,145687, 145600, 145730), 
(29990 ,145688, 145600, 145730), 
(56 ,145689, 145600, 145730), 
(968867 ,145690, 145600, 145730), 
(8452 ,145691, 145600, 145730), 
(1334 ,145679, 145600, 145730) ])

result_dict = rdd.filter(lambda x: x[2] <= x[1] <= x[3]).map(lambda x: (x[1] - x[2], 0))\
.countByKey()

print "minutes count of tweets"
for i in sorted(result_dict.iteritems()):
    print "{0}\t{1}".format(i[0], i[1])
```

Result:

```
minutes count of tweets
78  2
79  1
80  1
85  1
86  1
87  2
88  3
89  2
90  1
91  1
```